# RegEx exclude chars from expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following `RegEx`, that needed a modification:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,20}$
```

to not to allow to contains `{` and `}`

thnx

Comment: Which part shouldn't contain the brace characters?

Comment: What part should not allow `{` `}` and can you give some examples as what it should match and not match ?

Comment: I guess anywhere. this is a password regex chechker

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^{}]{6,20}$
```